# A problem with ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a problem with rendering `d3` (blue color), at the points of intersection of the red curve it makes vertical blue stripes, how do I fix it? Picture:

[image: plot]

```
MyPoint[o_, w_, a_, b_, c_, 
  t_] := {-(a*(o^2 - w^2) + b*o + c) + (2*a*o*w + b*w)*(
    w*Sin[w*t] - o*Cos[w*t])/(w*Cos[w*t] + o*Sin[w*t]), (o^2 + w^2)/(
   w*Cos[w*t] + o*Sin[w*t])*(2*a*o*w + b*w)*E^(t*o)}
MyPoint2[o_, r_, a_, b_, c_, 
  t_] := {r, -o*(r + (a*o^2 + b*o + c)/1)*E^(t*o)}
funkce[A_, B_, C_, T_, X1_, XN_, Y1_, YN_] := 
  Module[{a = A, b = B, c = C, t = T, x1 = X1, xn = XN, y1 = Y1, 
    yn = YN},
   (* d1 *)(*o = 0, w = 0, osa x*)
   
   d1 = ParametricPlot[{s, 0}, {s, x1, xn}, 
     PlotRange -> {{x1, xn}, {y1, yn}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Dashing[Large], Thickness[0.01], Black}];
        (* d2 *)(*o = 0, w > 0, hranice*)
        
   d2 = ParametricPlot[MyPoint[0, w, a, b, c, t], {w, 0, 200}, 
     PlotRange -> {{x1, xn}, {y1, yn}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Red}];
       (* d3 *)(*o > 0, w > 0*)
           
   d3 = ParametricPlot[
     MyPoint[o, w, a, b, c, t], {o, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 200}, 
     PlotRange -> {{x1, xn}, {y1, yn}}, PlotPoints -> 100];
   (*d4*) (*o > 0, w = 0*)
   
   d4 = ParametricPlot[
     MyPoint2[o, r, a, b, c, t], {o, 0, 40}, {r, x1, xn}, 
     PlotRange -> {{x1, xn}, {y1, yn}}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.2]]}, Mesh -> Full, 
     MeshStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.25]]}];
         Show[d3, d2, d1, d4]
   ];
tiskniPolynom[] := 
  Manipulate[
   funkce[a, b, c, t, x1, xn, y0, yn], {a, 1, InputField}, {b, 2, 
    InputField}, {c, 4, InputField}, {t, 0.31, InputField}, {x1, -1000,
     InputField}, {xn, 1000, InputField}, {y0, -1000, 
    InputField}, {yn, 1000, InputField}];
tiskniPolynom[]
```

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4`

Comment: @cvgmt If I add this code (PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4) to d3, all the plane is blue. :(